# iOS button frame incorrect on iPhone 6 simulator, works on iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, iphone, view, ios-simulator, loadview

In my view controller, my view is initialized in loadView method:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self loadViewController];

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}
```

The loadViewController method creates a button and adds it to the view. Here's a snippet from the loadViewController method that initializes and positions the button:

```
graphicalButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        graphicalButton.exclusiveTouch = YES;
        [graphicalButton setImage:kGraphicalIconSelected
                         forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [graphicalButton setImage:kGraphicalIconDeSelected
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [graphicalButton setFrame:CGRectMake(230, 100, 37, 34)];
        [graphicalButton addTarget:self
                            action:@selector(graphicalOptionAction:)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [graphicalButton setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
        NSLog(@"graphical button x %f",graphicalButton.frame.origin.x);
        [self.view addSubview:graphicalButton];
```

This displays the button correctly on an iPhone 4s simulator. The log statement logs the origin correctly as well.

However, on an iPhone 6 simulator, the log statement always logs the `origin.x` as 0. The button does not get displayed if the code runs. If however, I set up a breakpoint at the beginning of this code snippet and then step through each line, it logs the `origin.x` correctly and the button is displayed even on an iPhone 6 simulator.

I have even tried adding the call to `loadViewController` in `viewWillAppear` method, but even there the same issue occurs with this button. Any ideas on why this happens and how to resolve this?

Comment: Where do you declare graphicalButton?

Comment: Its an instance variable of the view controller.

Comment: Found the issue. The variable was declared as __weak. I made it a strong instance variable and that worked.